# Adding javascript functions to asp control

Tags: c#, asp.net

iv'e got an asp button which performs another task besides postback

i have done this by adding javascript code to the button as follows

```
       if( !IsPostBack )
            btn1.Attributes.Add("onclick", "f();");
```

i'm not sure of 2 things

the first :

where in the cs code i should add the function f() , currently i'm doing it in page load 
while ignoring postbacks because then the function would have already been added(i might be wrong)

the second :

is there any to make the function execute only if the page was validated ? (after postback)

thanks in advance
eran.

Comment: [Using JavaScript Along with ASP.NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479011.aspx) ?

Comment: yes... i got some client code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use OnClientClick instead of adding the click event throug the attributes. As for your JavaScript, I would add it in the ASPX part. Depending on what the function does, you might be able to avoid the code behind all together and do something like this:

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Hi" OnClientClick="javascript:return f();" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
```

From your f() function, kick off the validation, and return true if validation passes, otherwise return false. If OnClientClick returns true the page will post back, and if it returns false the page will not post back.

Comment: and don't use javascript:func - it's so 90's! The function name is sufficient.

Comment: thanks ,that was the right way to go. 
btw , could i have used my  validators through the java script ?
what i did is create my own validation in order to decide if to proceed or not , what i mean is if lets say i got a required field validator could i do something like 

RFValidator1.Validate()   ?

Comment: Yes, you can probably do your validation from within your JS function. Just call Page_ClientValidate()

Answer (score 1):

**1st Question**

You will need to add it each time.

```
btn1.Attributes.Add("onclick", "f();");
```

**2nd Question**

You can check the validity of a page by checking the `Page.IsValid` Property

Answer (score 0):

**[Unobtrusive JavaScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript)**

If you're serious about javascript then you don't want to write inline javascript. 
You will want to create an event handler in javascript code inside the script tags or in a external file.

If you're using .NET 4 server control id:s will be good, else I would use [jquery's
contains selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/). Search for the given server control ID.